# Unable to connect to MariaDB using EF Core in .NET 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, mariadb, .net-6.0

I am using DI for a web API and register my DbContext classes like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
    options => options.UseMySql(ServerVersion.AutoDetect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EntityFramework:MyDbContext:ConnectionStringKey")), 
    builder => builder.CommandTimeout(1800).EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null))
);
```

this is in my user secrets for the project:

```
"EntityFramework": {
  "PigDbContext": {
    "ConnectionStringKey": "server=pbr-dbs-01:3306;database=pb_db_operational;uid=root;pwd=myPassword;"
  }
}
```

During debugging, when I call the method I get a connection timeout exception after about 3-5 seconds, when the host tries to initialize the DbContext classes. The inner exception reads "Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts", but I am able to connect from my machine just fine when I use a database administration tool.

Any ideas what is causing this issue? I already tried rearranging the parameters in my connection string, as mentioned in another SO post regarding this error message. Someone else there mentioned VPN but since I am working from home, I cannot disable my VPN or I will lose connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the port properly. It needs to be a separate key:

```
Server=pbr-dbs-01; Port=3306; Database=pb_db_operational; Uid=root; Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: I had it in a seperate parameter like you say before I tried adding it to the server name. doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Which MySQL nuget package are you using?

Comment: I tried using Pomelo 6.0.0, I tried MySql.Data 8.0.27 (although their documentation only goes up to 8.0.23..) and I tried MySqlConnector, which I later learned is used by Pomelo. I am now using linq2db instead of EF because mysql.Data seems to work properly with it.